# SuperCollider without jack server

Tags: linux, alsa, jack, supercollider

One of the requirements in my project is to reduce runtime footprint on an embedded system. It looks like `jackd` is required on Linux and seem like it's currently a hard dependency and it cannot use `libasound` directly instead, is it true? It'd be also great to hear from someone who use `jackd` on an embedded device and could summaries it's resource usage. Although, I'm planing to use BeagleBone with relatively enough memory, I'd rather spare it for a longer delay line instead of running `jackd`.

Comment: It does look as though [SuperCollider requires jack on Linux](https://github.com/supercollider/supercollider/blob/master/README_LINUX.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jack is definitely the standard way of doing it for SuperCollider on Linux. There is an `AUDIOAPI` flag in the cmake build settings - you can set `-DAUDIOAPI=portaudio` when you make your own build. (There's no direct libasound implementation; supercollider is cross-platform.) However, be warned that the portaudio approach is rarely used and might not even work at the moment. If you need help getting a build working, ask [the sc-devel mailing list](http://www.birmingham.ac.uk/facilities/BEAST/research/supercollider/mailinglist.aspx).

On the other hand I know people have run jack+supercollider on small ARM devices such as beaglebones. You might find it a better use of your time to go with the flow and use jack.

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't bother with this, it's really a premature optimisation, just wanted to know a bit in advance...